# How to get middle part of string between definite symbols?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have strings like:
    "d:\tmp\abc_list.csv"
    "d:\tmp\xyzx_list.csv"
    "d:\tmp\qwert_list.csv"
I need to take first part of filename: abx,xyzc, qwert. I do it now as:

```
 string name = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1 , filename.IndexOf('_') - filename.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
```

I feel there should be easier and nicer way to do it. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is nice, but it is going to break if another part of the file name, say, part of its directory path, has an underscore. You should change it slightly to avoid this problem:

```
int pos = filename.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
string name = filename.Substring(pos , filename.IndexOf('_', pos) - pos);
```

When your solution is nice, robust, and easy to understand, there's no reason to go for a shorter solution. Of course you can use regular expression, but the resulting one-line solution is far less readable:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=\\)[^_\\]*(?=_[^\\]*$)")[0].Value;
```

Here is a [demo of this solution on ideone](http://ideone.com/Br1Trj).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Path` class:

```
string fullPath = @"d:\tmp\abc_list.csv";
string fileNameWOE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
string firstToken = fileNameWOE.Split('_').First();
```

Comment: The bonus of this is it treats filepaths as actual filepaths, not strings, so it has built-in handling for all the quirks of filepaths.

Comment: This is the best answer. The code is self-documenting, and it will correctly handle both regular slashes and backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path.aspx) class

and Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
string str = @"d:\tmp\abc_list.csv";

// The preferred way to manipulate paths is to use the Path.* methods
string str2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);

int ix = str2.LastIndexOf('_');

if (ix != -1)
{
    str2 = str2.Remove(ix);
}
```